# Jasmine-headless-webkit with guard (1.0.0) with rails 3.2; the asset compile is really slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, jasmine, ruby-on-rails-3.2, guard

Basically, when I save a file (coffeescript), guard compiles the assets then runs the test(s) relating to the file. This asset compile can take ~20 seconds. Guard prints the following:

```
Compiling rails assets with Guard::RailsAssets::RailsRunner.
rm -rf /Users/me/work/proj/public/assets
Assets compiled.
```

I just upgraded everything, and on the old system, the tests ran almost instantly. I'm not sure where to look to fix the slowdown.

I'm using:

- guard (1.0.0)
- guard-jasmine-headless-webkit (0.3.2)
- guard-rails-assets (0.1.3)
- rails (3.2.1)
- jasmine (1.1.2)
- jasmine-headless-webkit (0.8.4)

Previously, I was using:

- guard (0.6.2)
- guard-jasmine-headless-webkit (0.3.2)
- guard-rails-assets (0.0.7)
- rails (3.1.0)
- jasmine (1.0.2.1)
- jasmine-headless-webkit (0.8.0)

My guardfile has the following:

```
group 'frontend' do
  guard 'rails-assets' do
    watch('config/application.rb')
    watch(%r{^app/assets/javascripts/.*\.(js|coffee)$})
  end

  guard 'jasmine-headless-webkit', :full_run => false, :all_on_start => false do
    watch('spec/javascripts/support/jasmine.yml')  { |m| "spec/javascripts" }
    watch(%r{^app/assets/javascripts/(.*)\.(js|coffee)$}) do |m|
      # Don't run tests if there was a failure compiling the JS
      if Dir["public/assets/editor.js"].any?
        specific_file = newest_js_file("spec/javascripts/#{m[1]}")
        all_tests = "spec/javascripts"
        specific_file or all_tests
      end
    end
    watch(%r{^spec/javascripts/.*\.(js|coffee)$})
  end
end
```

This slowdown is killing my flow. If you need anymore info, let me know.